# Creating a simple calculator using bash and python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to write a small bash function that can do some basic calculations. I added this function to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
pyc() { python -c """from math import *; print($*)"""  ;}
```

However, when I want to calculate exp(5), I have to type

```
pyc exp\c(5\)
```

How could we modify the bash function, so that it works for

```
pyc exp(5)
```

Comment: Some symbols are interpreted by Bash. I suggest this workaround: `pyc 'exp(5)'`

Comment: @Cyrus I would accept the answer, If you write this as an answer.

Comment: Also, you can simplify it to `pyc() { python -c "from math import *; print($*)";}`

Comment: @PM2Ring does it work for pyc exp(5) ? it did not worked for me. says syntax error.

Comment: You still need to quote the Python expression as Cyrus said, otherwise Bash will try to interpret it instead of just passing it into the function.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks a lot for another syntax, but I was looking if we could avoid "" altogether ? I tried putting "" outside $*, but it did not work.

Comment: No, you should always quote parameters for Bash, unless you explicitly want word-splitting. Please see the [Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) article in BashGuide. But you can either use single quotes or double quotes around the Python expression; double-quotes let you pass Bash variables, eg `a=2; pyc "sqrt($a)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some symbols are interpreted by Bash. I suggest this workaround: `pyc 'exp(5)'`